# How to load the pages which are under the sub bookmark using pdf box?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to access the pages which are under the sub bookmark I do not have the any sample pdf to share and my work pdf is confidential. Below is the structure of the my pdf bookmark and under that there are 42 sub bookmarks. Each sub bookmarks have multiple pages. I am able to get to those sub bookmark. However, cannot iterate over those pages associated with that particular sub bookmark? Can anyone please suggest or help? I can share the code but cannot share the confidential pdf which I am working on.

```
MainBookMarkName
|_firstBookMark (1-10 pages)
 -page1
 -page2
 -page3
 -page4
 - .
 - .
 -page10
|_secondBookMark (1-5 pages)
 -page1
 -page2
 -page3
 -page4
 -page5
|_thirdBookMark (1-8 pages)
 -page1
 -page2
 -page3
 - .
 - .
 -page8
|_FourthBookMark
|_
|_
|_lastBookMark
```

Comment: How can one bookmark have multiple pages? When I click on one then I hit one page. I wonder if I am missing a concept. Please have a look at the file with PDFDebugger command line application, in the menu click "show internal structure", then go to `Root/Outlines` and look from there and make a screenshot when you've found what you need. The structure of bookmarks (outlines) is explained in https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf 12.3.3
Document Outline.

Comment: Basically these book mark comprises of forms. The pages of these forms are extended to more than 1 page (1-10 page) under the book mark. Not sure how can I loop or iterate over these pages? If I need to pick any page to resize, what can I use as an identifier to choose a specific page?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. Maybe somebody else has. Try find a non confidential file, e.g. a government form.

Comment: Sorry my document is confidential and I tried to find an pdf file online but couldn't find it. I have updated the design section above please let me know if that make sense. I am not sure if you have understood my question what I am trying to access? To iterate and access the pages under sub bookmark.

Comment: No, it is still a mystery for me. A bookmark may have a destination / action destination and that is one page. Or a bookmark can have bookmarks on a deeper level but that's not what you meant. All you could do would be to upload screenshots from PDFDebugger that do show what you mean but not anything confidential. PDF is so complex that I wouldn't be surprised if something completely new to me appears.

Comment: The "pages under the sub-bookmarks" look like sub-sub-bookmarks. Have you tried to access them as such?